Power Automate Cloud Flow launch sqlite
As I understand this, I want a Cloud flow, not a desktop flow.
I want to run sqlite3 queries on files stored on SharePoint as part of an automate power flow run on a schedule outside office hours.
My instinct is that I should be able to invoke sqlite3 via a command line call of some kind as long as sqlite3 is on the server and the relevant files are all on SharePoint.
However I cannot find a way to do this in Power Automate unless I'm doing a desktop flow, which doesn't seem like what I want.
I do not want to use ODBC connectors and process SQL inside power automate.  I'd like it done by sqlite3 if possible.

What’s the format of the files? JSON? CSV? Parquet?

@Skin From the point of view of the sqlite part, I'm starting with CSV files and importing, processing, creating views, etc., all done within sqlite.

I ask because if you want to run SQL over data that’s not in a DB, you can skip all of the pain and look at using the Advanced Data Operations connector. The Expert operation is a free for all on any data. There are other wrappers as well that make aggregating or other operations easy so you don’t need to write the SQL but Expert is fully flexible.   https://statesolutions.com.au/expert/
